# WAMP | Как подключиться к серверу с другой машины

Tags: apache, сервер, настройка, wamp

Подключение к сайту через localhost на основной машине работает.
Как сделать так, чтобы можно было подключиться к серверу через внешний ip.
Все порты открыты, только 80 толи открыт толи нет, не мониторится как остальные При попытки подключения через внешний IP, браузер говорит "Ожидение [ip]". Значит всё-таки подключение есть? 
Что делать?

Comment: С чего вы решили, что у вас порт открыт?

Comment: Открывал и в роутере и в брандмауере. Вроде всё работает, но почему-то 80 порт показывается закрытым.

Comment: Что работает и кто показывает закрытым? Кроме открытости портов, ещё нужно указывать с какой машиной в локальной сети этот порт ассоциировать (port forwarding).

Comment: Все порты открываются кроме 80, чекаю через PFP checker, В роутере Wan 0.0.0.0, локальный 192.168.0.11